# How to change Date format of column without convert into string in Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column of `CREATEDATE` its format is like `'2014-03-25 19:00:00'` in mysql database. I need to create another column with format `'2014-03-25'` without any conversion into a String or any other type. The Column should be `'DATE'` type only.

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: Simply do: `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columname DATE; UPDATE tablename SET columname=datetimecolumnname;`

Comment: If you store a DATETIME into a DATE column, you'll just get the date part of it. What more do you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD `date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT 
update tbl_name set date=CREATEDATE
```